# Python str to morse help needed

Tags: python

I am trying to write a program where you enter a string of letters/numbers/punctuation and it will come out the other end as Morse code.  I am getting an error that I do not know how to fix.  The error is:

```
Enter a string of letters you want to have converted to Morse code: This
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "morse.py", line 151, in <module>
main()
File "morse.py", line 149, in main
print(letter)
NameError: name 'letter' is not defined
```

My code is this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

def main():

# have user enter a string
letter_string = input('Enter a string of letters you want to have converted to Morse code: ')

# split the date
letter_list = letter_string.split('/')

    for ch in letter_list:
        if ch == 'a' or ch == 'A':
            letter == '.-'

        elif ch == 'b' or ch == 'B':
            letter == '-...'

        elif ch == 'c' or ch == 'C':
            letter == '-.-.'

        elif ch == 'd' or ch == 'D':
            letter == '-..'

        elif ch == 'e' or ch == 'E':
            letter == '.'

        elif ch == 'f' or ch == 'F':
            letter == '..-.'

        elif ch == 'g' or ch == 'G':
            letter == '--.'

        elif ch == 'h' or ch == 'H':
            letter == '....'

        elif ch == 'i' or ch == 'I':
            letter == '..'

        elif ch == 'j' or ch == 'J':
            letter == '.---'

        elif ch == 'k' or ch == 'K':
            letter == '-.-'

        elif ch == 'l' or ch == 'L':
            letter == '.-..'

        elif ch == 'm' or ch == 'M':
            letter == '--'

        elif ch == 'n' or ch == 'N':
            letter == '-.'

        elif ch == 'o' or ch == 'O':
            letter == '---'

        elif ch == 'p' or ch == 'P':
            letter == '.--.'

        elif ch == 'q' or ch == 'Q':
            letter == '--.-'

        elif ch == 'r' or ch == 'R':
            letter == '.-.'

        elif ch == 's' or ch == 'S':
            letter == '...'

        elif ch == 't' or ch == 'T':
            letter == '-'

        elif ch == 'u' or ch == 'U':
            letter == '..-'

        elif ch == 'v' or ch == 'V':
            letter == '...-'

        elif ch == 'w' or ch == 'W':
            letter == '.--'

        elif ch == 'x' or ch == 'X':
            letter == '-..-'

        elif ch == 'y' or ch == 'Y':
            letter == '-.-'

        elif ch == 'z' or ch == 'Z':
            letter == '--..'

        elif ch == '0':
            letter == '-----'

        elif ch == '1':
            letter == '.----'

        elif ch == '2':
            letter == '..---'

        elif ch == '3':
            letter == '...--'

        elif ch == '4':
            letter == '....-'

        elif ch == '5':
            letter == '.....'

        elif ch == '6':
            letter == '-....'

        elif ch == '7':
            letter == '--...'

        elif ch == '8':
            letter == '---..'

        elif ch == '9':
            letter == '----.'

        elif ch == ',':
            letter == '--..--'

        elif ch == '.':
            letter == '.-.-.-'

        elif ch == '?' or ch == 'C':
            letter == '..--..'

        else:
        '  '

       print(letter)
# call the main function        
main()
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: this would be implemented with a more OOP method, like a dict.

Answer (score 2):

You are using *equality comparison* (`==`) instead of *assignment* (`=`).

But, as @agconti points out, a dictionary is clearly the way to go:

```
morse = {'a': '.-', 'b': '-...', ...}

for ch in letter_list:
    letter = morse[ch.lower()]
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using the comparison operator instead of the assignment operator

```
==
```

is for comparison (it evaluates whether or not two values are equal)

```
=
```

is for assignment, it assigns the value on the right to the variable on the left.

Your ifs should be using

```
==
```

which is correct.

But your assignment should be

```
letter = "..."
```

so as to assign the value "..." to the variable letter.

Comment: One small add. Won't you also have to initialise letter first before actually printing it?

Comment: Nope, that's the danger/beauty of python and other dynamic languages.  Though if they want a default value, they can initialize it to some error condition